# Recover data from ibdata1 file only

Tags: mysql, database, data-recovery

As shown question title, it is clear that I want to recover data from ibdata1 file.  I had installed mysql in ubuntu system and corrupted around 189GB database. Now database is not gonna up and triggering millions of innodb log sequence number error.

Error

> 70925 14:14:34  InnoDB: Error: page 220865 log sequence number 2848448969864
>   InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2840085856559.
>   InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
>   InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: for more information.
>   170925 14:14:34  InnoDB: Error: page 220866 log sequence number 2842327184689
>   InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2840085856620.
>   InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
>   InnoDB: link
>   InnoDB: for more information.
>   170925 14:14:34  InnoDB: Error: page 220867 log sequence number 2848550606948
>   InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2840085856711.
>   InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
>   InnoDB: Link 
>   InnoDB: for more information.

I googles lots and tried many methods like -innodb_force_recovery=N (1 to 6) one by one with other changes too.. But DB is not gonna start up to recover data.

I already cleared DB and restored old backup and server is up and running now. But few data is very important and i want to recover it from ibdata1 file.

Can someone guide me how to recover data from ibdata1 file?

Here error log which might helpful.

```
        170925 14:14:34  InnoDB: Error: page 2804483 log sequence number 2846912445106
        InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2840085857093.
        InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
        InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
        InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
        InnoDB: for more information.
        170925 14:14:34  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140499101235072 in file trx0rseg.c line 144
        InnoDB: Failing assertion: UT_LIST_GET_LEN(rseg->update_undo_list) == 0
        InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
        InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
        InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
        InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
        InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
        InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
        InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
        08:44:34 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
        This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
        or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
        or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
        We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
        diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
        something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
        key_buffer_size=16777216
        read_buffer_size=131072
        max_used_connections=0
        max_threads=500
        thread_count=0
        connection_count=0
        It is possible that mysqld could use up to
        key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1110145 K  bytes of memory
        Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
        Thread pointer: 0x0
        Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
        where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
        terribly wrong...
        stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x7fc87f558400]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x7fc87f442a35]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fc87e1d3340]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39)[0x7fc87d829bb9]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7fc87d82cfc8]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a0e0f)[0x7fc87f608e0f]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5a3d00)[0x7fc87f60bd00]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x590f2a)[0x7fc87f5f8f2a]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55c036)[0x7fc87f5c4036]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22ha_finalize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x2b)[0x7fc87f4449bb]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2ffa29)[0x7fc87f367a29]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x303a71)[0x7fc87f36ba71]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15plugin_shutdownv+0x1cd)[0x7fc87f36cbed]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x289cf1)[0x7fc87f2f1cf1]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(unireg_abort+0x1c3)[0x7fc87f2f27f3]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x28b2e8)[0x7fc87f2f32e8]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x7fc87f2f751b]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fc87d814ec5]
        /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x286a78)[0x7fc87f2eea78]
        The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
        information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It Solved by starting database with /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &**

Comment: What do you mean by this?